# Assemble rule replacement from pairs of positions

Tags: list-manipulation, sparse-arrays

I want to create a rule replacement list, which I then use to create a `SparseArray`.  The input is a list of positions of the from `{{startPosition, stopPosition}, ...}`.

The following function works fine as long as the input has the `startPosition` and `stopPosition` in sequence.

```
buildBinaryTrace[pos_] := # -> 1 & /@ 
 Flatten[Subdivide[First@#, Last@#, Last@# - First@#] & /@ pos ] 

 pos = {{1,5}, {10,11}, {15,20}}

 buildBinaryTrace[pos]
```

Gives Result

> ```
> {1 -> 1, 2 -> 1, 3 -> 1, 4 -> 1, 5 -> 1, 10 -> 1, 11 -> 1, 15 -> 1, 
>   16 -> 1, 17 -> 1, 18 -> 1, 19 -> 1, 20 -> 1}
> ```

However the same function gives an Error due to the `Subdivide` function if the two positions are the same (indicating that only one number should be changed to a `1`.

For example

```
tstPos = {{1,5}, {7,8}, {10,10}}
```

should give result

> ```
>  { 1->1, 2-> 1, 3-> 1, 4-> 1, 5-> 1, 7-> 1, 8-> 1, 10-> 1}
> ```

but I get an error.

I have tried modifying the function to

```
 tstbuildBinaryTrace[pos_] := Module[{start = 0, stop = 0}, 
   {start, stop} = {First@#, Last@#} & /@ pos;
   If[stop - start != 0,
    # -> 1 & /@ Flatten[Subdivide[start, stop, stop - start] ],
    start -> 1]
   ]
```

But some how i'm mapping incorrectly and get an error.

I'm looking for a solution that can either generate the correct list to create the sparse array or a solution that generates the correct `SparseArray` directly.  I suspect making the `SparseArray` directly may be even faster/more elegant but I was unable to figure out how to do this.   Speed is most important to me, so I will select the fastest solution if multiple solutions are provided.

Comment: Could tell more about how your desired sparse array should look like at the end?

Comment: @kuba The sparse Array is representing a signal I am processing.  The positions places where the signal is "on" get 1's in the sparse array and the positions where the signal is "off" get zeros.  The positions i'm inputting into this function are the range of positions that the signal is "on".  So the coordinates `{ {5,10}, {12,12} }` indicates that the signal was off from frame 1-4.  On from 5-10.  Off at 11. and On at 12.  The length of the sparse array should be the length of signal I am processing.  In this example all my signals have length of 300.

Comment: I see, thanks. Are there any concerns about the answer?

Comment: @kuba no concern about answer. I am waiting to accept in case I get an answer that builds the sparse array directly so I can compare timings

Comment: Sure, no need to hurry, just wanted to check if that fits your goal well or any adjustments are needed. Good luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about:

```
buildBinaryTrace := Thread[Flatten[Range @@@ #] -> 1] &
```

your problem will be fixed since `Range[10,10]` gives only `{10}`.

---

```
buildBinaryTrace@{{1, 5}, {7, 8}, {10, 10}}
```

> ```
> {1 -> 1, 2 -> 1, 3 -> 1, 4 -> 1, 5 -> 1, 7 -> 1, 8 -> 1, 10 -> 1}
> ```

```
buildBinaryTrace@{{1, 5}, {10, 11}, {15, 20}}
```

> ```
> {1 -> 1, 2 -> 1, 3 -> 1, 4 -> 1, 5 -> 1, 10 -> 1, 11 -> 1, 15 -> 1, 
>  16 -> 1, 17 -> 1, 18 -> 1, 19 -> 1, 20 -> 1}
> ```